# UPDATE: Enumerating instead of summing in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, enumeration

I have a 2 part problem in Python that I would need a help in.
I have the following two inputs.
The first one provides mapping information: ie:

```
amphibian   anm|art|art|art|art
anaconda    anm
```

The second one provides the data to be mapped: ie:

```
amphibian   first   heador  10
anaconda    first   heador  2
anaconda    second  hello   1
```

The objective of this program is to replace the individual word in the first column of the second file with a corresponding category, as found in the second column in the first file.

Thus, the desired results are as follows, which consider the frequency of the second and third columns that pertain to the concept in the first column, enumerating each possibility:

```
anm second  hello   1.0
anm first   heador  10.0 
anm first   heador  2.0 
art first   heador  10.0
art first   heador  10.0
art first   heador  10.0
art first   heador  10.0
```

In my code, however, I am coming across the following problem, in which instead of enumerating each of the second and third columns with their respective category, it sums the values of the fourth column, if the 1, 2 and 3 columns are identical, such as:

```
anm second  hello   1.0
anm first   heador  12.0
art first   heador  40.0
```

In which the values in the 4th column are being summed if the other columns are identical.

The part of the code which I think the problem is coming from is here:

```
with open(infile, "rb") as input:           
    for line in input:
        uLine = unicode(line, "latin1")
        lemmaTAR, slot, filler, freq = uLine.split()
        if lemmaTAR in lemmas:
            senses = mapping[lemmaTAR].split(u'|')
            sense_number = len(senses)
            for sense in senses:
                        **classFreqs[sense][slot][filler] += int(freq)** #/ sense_number
        else:
            pass
```

In which I try to increment the variable with **+=**
However, it does not give me the desired results.
When I try to define classFreqs[sense][slot][filler]  as **classFreqs[sense][slot][filler] = int(freq)** , it only considers the first value found, giving me the following results:

```
anm second  hello   1
anm first   heador  2
art first   heador  10
```

which is also not correct because it does not consider the imbalance of the categories as found in the index input.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to solve this quick basic (yet very frustrating) issue that I have come across?
Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

I have implemented the code suggestion below by @Hugh Bothwell

Which has produced the results:

```
[(u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 10)]
[(u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10)]
[(u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10)]
[(u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10)]
[(u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10)]
[(u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 2)]
[(u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10), (u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 2), (u'anm', u'second', u'hello', 1)]
```

Thus, A. I am not sure what I am doing wrong...
B. when I have tried to print the output (i.e.)
:

```
with open('output', 'wb') as oOutFile:
    for sense in results:
            for slot in results[sense]:
                for fill in results[sense][slot]:
                    outstring = '\t'.join([sense, slot, fill,\
                                       str(results[sense][slot][fill])])


                    oOutFile.write(outstring.encode("utf8") + '\n')
```

It gives me the following traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SOcode_example.py", line 18, in <module>
    for slot in results[sense]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: In the code snippet you say `+=`, in the text you say `=+`, and then later you say just `=`: `classFreqs[sense][slot][filler] = int(freq)`. Please check which it is in the code you are running: if it is either of the latter two, then that explains your problem precisely.

Comment: I fixed the text. The results reported are obtained using `+=`. In the last example, I show what is the (obviously) incorrect output when using just `=`. I was just trying to show my trials and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lemmas = {}
with open("lemmas.txt", "rb") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        lem, senses = unicode(line, "latin1").split()
        lemmas[lem] = senses.split("|")

results = []
with open("input.txt", "rb") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        lemmaTAR, slot, filler, freq = unicode(line, "latin1").split()
        freq = int(freq)
        for sense in lemmas.get(lemmaTAR, []):
            results.append((sense, slot, filler, freq))
```

which produces results =

```
[
    (u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 10),
    (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10),
    (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10),
    (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10),
    (u'art', u'first', u'heador', 10),
    (u'anm', u'first', u'heador', 2),
    (u'anm', u'second', u'hello', 1)
]
```

**Edit:** looking at your output, you are obviously appending to results then printing cumulative results at each step. *Either* append at each step then print when complete, *or* print at each step; don't try to do both.

```
with open('output', 'wb') as outf:
    lines = ("\t".join(res) for res in results)
    outf.write("\n".join(lines).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I have implemented your code suggestion and have the following result, please see updated question!